Why are two layers merged in GEE and how to seperate them?
I have flooded and permanent water layer selection through the following code:

    jrcSurfaceWater = ee.ImageCollection('JRC/GSW1_3/YearlyHistory') \
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(start_year, end_year, 'year')) \
        .map(lambda image: image.select('waterClass').eq(3)) \
        .mean() \
        .clip(AoI) \
        .visualize(min=0, max=1, palette=['blue'])  
     
    mapIdWater = jrcSurfaceWater.getMapId()

    jrcSurfaceFlood = ee.ImageCollection('JRC/GSW1_3/YearlyHistory') \
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(start_year, end_year, 'year')) \
        .map(lambda image: image.select('waterClass').eq(2)) \
        .mean() \
        .clip(AoI) \
        .visualize(min=0, max=1, palette=['red'])
        
    mapIdFlood = jrcSurfaceFlood.getMapId()

This is Python code and the resulting layers and being sent to frontend to be displayed. I don't know why the permanent water layer and flood layer are merged into one layer. Both the jrcSurfaceFlood and jrcSurfaceWater are showing same merged layers with different colors red and blue, even though I have set waterClass equals to 2 and 3 seperately for flood and permanent water.

I was able to get two seperate layers by the following code:
   jrcSurfaceWater = ee.ImageCollection('JRC/GSW1_3/YearlyHistory') \
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(start_year, end_year, 'year')) \
        .map(lambda image: image.select('waterClass').eq(3)) \
        .mean() \
        .clip(AoI)
    jrcSurfaceWater = jrcSurfaceWater.updateMask(jrcSurfaceWater.gt(0)) 
    jrcSurfaceWater = jrcSurfaceWater.visualize(min=0, max=1, palette=['blue'])
        
    jrcSurfaceFlood = ee.ImageCollection('JRC/GSW1_3/YearlyHistory') \
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(start_year, end_year, 'year')) \
        .map(lambda image: image.select('waterClass').eq(2)) \
        .mean() \
        .clip(AoI)
    jrcSurfaceFlood = jrcSurfaceFlood.updateMask(jrcSurfaceFlood.gt(0)) 
    jrcSurfaceFlood = jrcSurfaceFlood.visualize(min=0, max=1, palette=['red'])

